# Get calling cell address in Google Apps Script custom function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to use the cell address (of the cell the formula is in) in a custom formula.
e.g. In my sheet I have a formula in cell C7: =fSomeFormula()
In my code I need something like

```
function fSomeFormula(){
  var a = source.getA1Notation();
  var b = source.getRow();
  var c = source.getColumn();
  return [a,b,c]; //returns ["C7",7,3]
};
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you trying to get the cell to first calculate something, then refer to itself to make yet another calculation?  If so, wouldn't this create a circular reference error?

Comment: I want to return an array which size depends on the address of my formula. I have solved it now by passing an extra 'size' variable.

Answer (score 2):

This is not documented, but calling [`getActiveCell()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactivecell) [or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61905950/whats-the-difference-between-getactivecell-and-getcurrentcell-in-google-apps-sc) [`getCurrentCell()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getcurrentcell) *in custom functions* returns the Range of the cell calling the function, **not** the "active" cell or "the cell that has focus in the Google Sheets UI, and is highlighted by a dark border".

So the answer is,

```js
function currentCell() {
  const cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCurrentCell();
  return `[${cell.getA1Notation()}, ${cell.getRow()}, ${cell.getColumn()}]`;
}
```

[image: get current cell address in Google Apps Script custom function]

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the built-in functions.

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(), 4)
```

Comment: Hi Amit, that is not going to work, I need the address in my formula to calculate with.

Comment: You can write a custom function with parameters and pass row() and column() to the function.

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick but I was looking for a more elegant solution. I guess the answer to my question is 'no' then :-)