# How to reference a row in the first sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there any easy way to reference a row in an index-named sheet?

```
function rowInSheet(sheetIndex, range) {
  try {
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    if ((sheetIndex > 0) && (sheetIndex <= sheets.length)) 
        return sheets[(sheetIndex - 1)].getRange(range).getValue();
    else return "invalid sheet #";
  }
  catch (err) {
    return "#ERROR!"
  }
}
```

But I when I try to run it with `rowInSheet(1, B356)` I get an `#Error`.

Comment: I think that your custom formula of `rowInSheet(1, B356)`, the value of `B356` is given. In this case, when the value is not the A1Notation, an error occurs at `getRange(range)`. So please put `=rowInSheet(1, "B356")` to a cell by giving the A1Notation of `B356` as the string value. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: These threads might be the answer for your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/14389205 https://stackoverflow.com/q/33259686