# What's the difference between getActiveCell and getCurrentCell in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've read the definitions a few times over and I still don't understand the difference.

**getActiveCell: Range**

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getActiveCell()
- **Summary:** Returns the active cell in this sheet.
- **Description:** Returns the active cell in this sheet.

**getCurrentCell: Range**

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getCurrentCell()
- **Summary:** Returns the current cell in the active sheet or null if there is no current cell.
- **Description:** Returns the current cell in the active sheet or null if there is no current cell. The current cell is the cell that has focus in the Google Sheets UI, and is highlighted by a dark border. There is never more than one current cell. When a user selects one or more cell ranges, one of the cells in the selection is the current cell.

---

There's this note in getActiveCell's documentation: (copy-pasted including grammatical errors)

> It's preferrable to use getCurrentCell(), which the returns the current highlighted cell.

Which doesn't make it any clearer

Comment: I think that both methods returns the same values and can be used for the same way. The difference might be the following points. The method of `getActiveCell()` in Class Sheet and Class Spreadsheet had added before [2010](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2011#january_21_2011_to_february_18_2011). The method of `getCurrentCell()` in Class Sheet and Class Spreadsheet has been added at [April 11, 2018](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2018). From this, the internal scripts for each method might be difference.

Comment: @Tanaike They are not quite the same. If you have a selected range, then depending on how the range has been selected, [`getActiveCell()` and `getCurrentCell()` will return different ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61916082/11551468).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Answer:

*`getCurrentCell()` returns the highlighted cell as seen by the dark border in the Sheets UI, whereas `getActiveCell()` returns the top-left cell of the selected range.*

#### Example:

Say you have a range highlighted in a Sheet: `B2:E10`, for example. In the case where the you clicked on `B2` and dragged down to `E10`:

[image]

Running the following code in the script editor:

```
function getCells() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  console.log(sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation())
  console.log(sheet.getCurrentCell().getA1Notation())
}
```

You will see in the logs that both `getActiveCell()` and `getCurrentCell()` return `B2`.

However in the opposite scenario, where you clicked on `E10` and dragged up to `B2`:

[image]

After running the same code, you will see that `getActiveCell()` still returns `B2`, but now `getCurrentCell()` returns `E10`.

Comment: If called from a custom function, both seem to return the cell that the function was called from. Can anyone comment on this? @Tanaike?