# Being iterate through all pasted into cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to call an external API for every cell that gets pasted into in my spreadsheet using either an onEdit on onChange trigger, neither seem to work completely when the selected cells are non-contiguous. No matter whether I use

```
SpreadsheetApp.getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges()
```

or

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveRangeList().getRanges()
```

it only ever returns a single range that is the first-selected range. When I run the function directly, it works fine, but when triggered, it does not. I'm guessing this is either a bug or is just plain ol' impossible, but I'm hoping I'm just missing something.

Sheet:
[image: sheet]

Console log:

[image: console log]

```
function updateCategoryOnChange(e) {
  var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getSelection()
  var rangeList = selection.getActiveRangeList()

  //var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  //var sheet=ss.getActiveSheet()
  //var rangeList=sheet.getActiveRangeList()
  

  var ranges=rangeList.getRanges()
  Logger.log("ranges length "+ranges.length);
  for (var i=0; i<ranges.length; i++) {
    Logger.log('x '+ranges[i].getA1Notation()+' '+ranges[i].getNumRows()+' rows, '+ranges[i].getNumColumns()+' columns')
  }
  return;
```

Comment: Hi, was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66747185) useful?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.  Here's my logger output

```
Mar 19, 2021, 3:38:34 PM    Info    ranges length 1
Mar 19, 2021, 3:38:34 PM    Info    x G5:G12 8 rows, 1 columns
```

I ran it with an installable onEdit trigger

Here's a bigger paste:

```
Mar 19, 2021, 3:40:58 PM    Info    ranges length 1
Mar 19, 2021, 3:40:58 PM    Info    x K8:P18 11 rows, 6 columns
```

if you add the toast below you can tell when it runs:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('entry');
  var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getSelection();
  var rangeList = selection.getActiveRangeList();
  var ranges=rangeList.getRanges()
  Logger.log("ranges length "+ranges.length);
  for (var i=0; i<ranges.length; i++) {
    Logger.log('x '+ranges[i].getA1Notation()+' '+ranges[i].getNumRows()+' rows, '+ranges[i].getNumColumns()+' columns')
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, since it's an installed trigger, the 30 second limit doesn't apply.

Comment: @lamblichus Thanks I wasn't sure about that.

Comment: It looks like yours is a single, contiguous range, correct? My issue is when multiple, non-contiguous ranges are selected, only the first one is returned.

Comment: According to the history you added more to the question after my answer so it wasn't clear to me that was the issue.  Butt I'd go with the lamblichus answer

Answer (score 0):

#### This seems to be a bug.

Multiple ranges cannot currently be retrieved via `onEdit` trigger (or via `onChange`, for that matter).

[getActiveRangeList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactiverangelist), in this case, will only retrieve the range corresponding to [getCurrentCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getcurrentcell) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61916082) for more details on the difference between `getCurrentCell()` and `getActiveCell()`).

This behaviour was reported in Issue Tracker:

- [I can't get multiple separated selected ranges by getActiveRangeList() in onEdit triggered function.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115931946)

To anyone affected by this, I'd suggest [subscribing to this issue by starring it](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue) in order to keep track of this and to help prioritizing it.