# How do I get the current cell in a Google Apps Script function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a Google Sheet. In that sheet, I have a readonly cell that calls a custom function called `formatCell`. In that function, I need to dynamically set the number format. I know I can set the number format using the `setNumberFormat` function. To demonstrate, here is where I'm at:

```
function formatCell(p) {
  var cell = null; // TODO: Get the cell that calls `formatCell`
  if (p === 1) {
    cell.setNumberFormat("0.000");
  } else if (p === 2) {
    cell.setNumberFormat("# ?/?");
  }
}
```

What I don't know is how to get the cell that *calls* `formatCell`. I know there is a [getCurrentCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getCurrentCell()) function. However, that function gets the cell with the current focus. I need to get the cell that is calling `formatCell`. How do I do that?

Comment: Google Sheets hasn't "readonly" cells. Do you mean protected cell? By the other hand, the custom function is missing a return statement with the corresponding value.

Comment: This is not documented, but [calling `getCurrentCell()` from a custom function returns the calling cell, not the cell that has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405787/get-calling-cell-address-in-google-apps-script-custom-function/76500686#76500686). You can show this easily by having multiple calls to that custom function in the sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the cell containing the formula use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()`.

Please bear in mind that custom functions can't change cells characteristics, they can only return a value or an array of values.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveRange()
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Comment: Because of this restriction, it seems like you could simply have the function format p the way you want and then return it as a string "1.000" or "# 2/1" etc (admitting I don't recognize the second number format).